# Autofilter in Excel output from JasperReports Server not working

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I can get the *Autofilter* to work when I run a report in *iReport*, however when I run the same report from *JasperReports Server*, the *Autofilter* does not appear.

Is there any special configuration I need for *Autofilter* to work from *JR Server*?

Comment: what version of ireport and jasperreports server are you using?